# Webpack treeshaking with exporting const variables

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, webpack

Our setup:
- Angular 5.2.x
- Ionic 4.4.x.
- Webpack 3.6.x

We have a app-structure like this:

```
app
  |__features
  |    |__Feature1
  |    |     |__Feature1Service.ts
  |    |     |__Feature1Dto.ts
  |    |     |__index.ts
  |    |
  |    |__Feature2
  |          |__Feature2Service.ts
  |          |__Feature2Dto.ts
  |          |__index.ts
  |
  |__core
       |__SomeCoreStuff.ts
       |__index.ts
```

In index files we export everything which is needed outside the current feature like this:

```
import { Feature1Service } from './Feature1Service';
import { Feature1Dto } from './Feature1Dto';
export const fromFeature1 = { Feature1Service, Feature1Dto };
```

and the usage then looks like this e.g. in Feature2:

```
import { fromFeature1 } from '../Feature1';

//use Feature1Service but not Feature1Dto
fromFeature1.Feature1Service;
```

In this case only one property on `const fromFeature1` is used.

Our question is if webpack's treeshaking strips the not used export (Feature1Dto in this case). If not how much does that blow up our deployed js bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromFeature1.Feature1Service` is `fromFeature1` object property. It isn't an export and cannot be tree-shaken if `fromFeature1` is in use.

In order to use tree shaking, it should be:

```
export { Feature1Service } from './Feature1Service';
export { Feature1Dto } from './Feature1Dto';
```

Comment: Does treeshaking work if we do `export * from './Feature1Service'; export * from './Feature1Dto';` in the index-file and then `import * as fromFeature1 from './Feature1'`?

Comment: Yes, that's how tree shakIng works, at least in current webpack versions.